# HHVM MongoDb aggregation seems like it doesn't work

Tags: php, mongodb, hhvm

I have some php script running on hhvm
I'm trying to get max value of numeric field from my collection in MongoDB 3.2
Here is my aggregation pipeline

```
    $mongo = new \MongoDB\Driver\Manager(MONGODB_HOST);
    $myCollection = new \MongoDB\Collection($mongo, "mydb.mycollection");

    $pipeline = [
            [
                '$group' => [
                    '_id' => 'group_field',
                    'slId' => ['$max' => '$saleId']
                ],
            ]
        ];

    $doc = $myCollection->aggregate($pipeline);
```

This pipeline perfectly works in mongo shell, but from php $doc contains all documents from my collection and no $group is applied to them
Maybe someone can help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aggregation operation is returning all documents from your collection since you are specifying a constant value for the group by key, the string `group_field`. You need to prefix the group field with the `$` character in your `_id` key value. So for example if your group by key is the `name` field, you can rewrite the aggregation pipeline as

```
$mongo = new \MongoDB\Driver\Manager(MONGODB_HOST);
$myCollection = new \MongoDB\Collection($mongo, "mydb.mycollection");
$group_field = '$name';
$pipeline = [
        [
            '$group' => [
                '_id' => $group_field,
                'slId' => ['$max' => '$saleId']
            ],
        ]
    ];

$doc = $myCollection->aggregate($pipeline);
```

Comment: i've tried but it doesn't helps, still have all documents as a result and no $group effect or slId field :(
but db.mycollection.aggregate({ $group : { _id : 'group_field', last : { $max : "$saleId"}} }) works fine in mongo shell

Comment: Can you edit your question to include some sample documents for testing? I'm pretty sure you need to prefix the field name you are grouping by with `$` for the `$group` operator to group documents by this key, else it will be treated as a constant and will group all documents into a single result.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to chridam's answer up here.
I don't know, but maybe this is some kind of magic
So, chridam's answer helped me with $group, so finally my results were grouped by $group_field. But slId still wasn't there. So, here is what i did and it helped:

```
$f = '$group_field';
$sl = ['$max' => '$saleId'];
$pipeline = array(
    array(
        '$group' => array(
            '_id'  => $f,
            'slId' => $sl
        ),
    )
);
```